# Get Context of a Service

Tags: token, android-service, android-context, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to get the context of my Service in order. The service opens up an overlay that draws on other apps. The overlay comes up but if I interact with any of the views, the app crashes and gives this error.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Here is the full error.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:340)
    at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.show(Spinner.java:1146)
    at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:792)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

From what I've been able to determine through Google Search and SO is that the issue is with the context. Below is the code for my Service.

```
class Dooa: Service() {

private lateinit var floatView: ViewGroup
private lateinit var floatWindowLayoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams
private var LAYOUT_TYPE: Int? = null
private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager
private lateinit var spinnerAccount: Spinner
private lateinit var tvDateAT: TextView
private lateinit var spinnerType: Spinner
private lateinit var etTitle: EditText
private lateinit var etMemo: EditText
private lateinit var spinnerCategory: Spinner
private lateinit var spinnerDebitOrCredit: Spinner
private lateinit var etAmount: EditText
private lateinit var ibSave: ImageButton
private lateinit var ibCancel: ImageButton
private var account: String = "Joint"
private var debitOrCredit: String = "Debit"
private var category: String = ""
private var type: String = "CC"
private var mils: Long = 0
private var balance: String = ""
private var context: Context? = null
private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    context = MyApp().getContext()

    Log.d("blocks", "context: $context")

    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.action == START) {

            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

            val metrics = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics
            val width = metrics.widthPixels
            val height = metrics.heightPixels

            windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

            val inflator = this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            floatView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.dooa_transaction_card, null) as ViewGroup

            spinnerAccount = floatView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAccount)
            tvDateAT = floatView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateAT)
            spinnerType = floatView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerType)
            etTitle = floatView.findViewById(R.id.etTitle)
            etMemo = floatView.findViewById(R.id.etMemo)
            spinnerCategory = floatView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory)
            spinnerDebitOrCredit = floatView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDebitOrCredit)
            etAmount = floatView.findViewById(R.id.etAmount)
            ibSave = floatView.findViewById(R.id.ibSave)
            ibCancel = floatView.findViewById(R.id.ibCancel)

            //ACCOUNT SPINNER
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.accounts,
                R.layout.spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->

                Log.d("blocks", "AS ArrayAdapter ran")

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)

                spinnerAccount.adapter = adapter
                spinnerAccount.setSelection(0)
            }

            spinnerAccount.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {

                    val selection = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)

                    account = selection.toString()
                    getDB()

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }

            }

            tvDateAT.setOnClickListener {
                
                val c = Calendar.getInstance()
                val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

                val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
                    this@Dooa,
                    { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

                        // Save milliseconds for date picked.
                        mils = c.timeInMillis
                        val m = monthOfYear + 1
                        // Display Selected date in textbox
                        tvDateAT.text = getString(
                            R.string.date_picked,
                            m.toString(),
                            dayOfMonth.toString(),
                            year.toString()
                        )

                    },
                    year,
                    month,
                    day
                )

                dpd.show()

            }

            //TYPE
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.type,
                R.layout.spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)

                spinnerType.adapter = adapter
                spinnerType.setSelection(0)
            }

            spinnerType.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    val selection = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)

                    type = selection.toString()

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            }

            etTitle.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
                override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    etTitle.isCursorVisible = true
                    val updatedFloatParamsFlag = floatWindowLayoutParams
                    updatedFloatParamsFlag.flags =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    updatedFloatParamsFlag.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatView, updatedFloatParamsFlag)
                    return false
                }
            })

            //CATEGORY
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.category,
                R.layout.spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)

                spinnerCategory.adapter = adapter
                spinnerCategory.setSelection(0)
            }

            spinnerCategory.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    val selection = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)

                    category = selection.toString()

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            }

            //DEBIT OR CREDIT
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.debit_or_credit,
                R.layout.spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)

                spinnerDebitOrCredit.adapter = adapter
                spinnerDebitOrCredit.setSelection(0)
            }

            spinnerDebitOrCredit.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    val selection = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)

                    debitOrCredit = selection.toString()

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            }

            ibSave.setOnClickListener {
                // save all the info.
                val date = tvDateAT.text
                val memo = etMemo.text
                val title = etTitle.text
                val amount = etAmount.text
                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                val serverTS = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                val collection = account


                var nb = 0.0
                val newBalance = if (debitOrCredit.contains("Debit")){
                    nb = (balance.toDouble() - etAmount.text.toString().toDouble())
                } else {
                    nb = (balance.toDouble() + etAmount.text.toString().toDouble())
                }

                val info = hashMapOf(
                    "date" to date.toString(),
                    "type" to type,
                    "title" to title.toString(),
                    "memo" to memo.toString(),
                    "category" to category,
                    "debitOrCredit" to debitOrCredit,
                    "amount" to amount.toString(),
                    "clearReconcile" to "NA",
                    "mils" to mils,
                    "timeStamp" to serverTS
                )

        if (date != "Date"){

            if (title?.isNotEmpty() == true && amount?.isNotEmpty() == true){

                val dbAccountTransaction = db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection(collection)
                dbAccountTransaction.add(info)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {

                        db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection(collection).document("balance")
                            .update("balance", nb.toString())
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Transaction was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(i)
                            }

                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error. Transaction wasn't saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out Title and Amount.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a date.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

            }

            ibCancel.setOnClickListener {
                stopSelf()
                windowManager.removeView(floatView)
            }

            LAYOUT_TYPE = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            } else {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST
            }

            floatWindowLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                (width * 0.55f).toInt(),
                (height * 0.55f).toInt(),
                LAYOUT_TYPE!!,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )

            floatWindowLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            floatWindowLayoutParams.x = 0
            floatWindowLayoutParams.y = 0

            windowManager.addView(floatView, floatWindowLayoutParams)

            floatView.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{

                val updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam = floatWindowLayoutParams
                private var initialX = 0.0
                private var initialY = 0.0
                private var initialTouchX = 0.0
                private var initialTouchY = 0.0

                override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            initialX = updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam.x.toDouble()
                            initialY = updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam.y.toDouble()
                            initialTouchX = event.rawX.toDouble()
                            initialTouchY = event.rawY.toDouble()
                            return true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam.x = (initialX + event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                            updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam.y = (initialY + event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatView, updatedFloatWindowLayoutParam)
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }


            })

            spinnerAccount.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
                override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    val updatedFloatParamsFlag = floatWindowLayoutParams
                    updatedFloatParamsFlag.flags =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatView, updatedFloatParamsFlag)
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

private fun getDB() {
    try {
        db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
            .collection(account).document("balance")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    val balanceResult = StringBuffer()
                    balanceResult.append(document.data?.getValue("balance"))
                    balance = balanceResult.toString()
                }
            }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    stopSelf()
    windowManager.removeView(floatView)
}

companion object {
    var FOREGROUND_SERVICE_ID = 101
    var START = "start"
    var STOP_ACTION = "stop"
    private const val CHANNEL = "default"
}
```

}

I have tried several ways of getting the context, but it always seems to come back null. I have tried this, this@Dooa, this.applicationContext, I also created a class MyApp to get context that way. it didn't work either. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25821214/14594074). Code below.

```
class MyApp: Application() {

private var context: Context? = null

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    context = applicationContext
}

fun getContext(): Context? {
    return context?.applicationContext
}
```

}

I've also checked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446264/14594074) about Service is a Context, but I still haven't been able to get this to work.

I have tried the code in the onCreate first then I tried the onStartCommand to no avail. What am I missing?

The window pops up, It pops up with a button click, or from a notification, either way if I click on a view, it gives me the error at the top of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
context = MyApp().getContext()
```

This is definitely wrong. `MyApp` is an Android component. You are not allowed to instantiate Android components yourself. Only the Android framework can do this (as it also sets up the `Context` and other important values.

If you want the `Service` context, just use `this` (A `Service` **is a `Context`**).

If you want the application context, just use `getApplication()` (`Application` **is also a `Context`**).